# vscode auto imports not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, auto-import

My vscode only auto imports modules if the files they are contained in are opened in the editor. For example if I want to import `<Component/>` from `Component.js`, I have to open the `Component.js` file first in the IDE and only then auto suggestion 'finds' it and suggests it. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Maybe related to this recent issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038328/why-is-vs-code-importing-from-hoist-non-react-statics-node-modules-types-react